# "Telescope" project (of METEOR) installed on Windows, but cannot start

Tags: windows, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I installed the latest "Telescope" project in my Windows 8 environment for Meteor 0.8.1.3 (already installed in Windows). Note, that the latest "Telescope" project does support Meteor 0.8.

I did clone all the related git repositories of the its packages.

When I run the app (through "meteor run") everything seems to be built OK, but then after the "Started MongoDB" message the following errors are appearing (and being repeated for every some seconds):

```
=> Started proxy.

=> Started MongoDB.

W20140608-02:12:51.171(3)? (STDERR)

W20140608-02:12:51.172(3)? (STDERR)
C:\Users\nm2arch\AppData\Local\.meteor\tools\edf8981bb6\lib\node_modules\fibere.js:173

W20140608-02:12:51.173(3)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);

W20140608-02:12:51.175(3)? (STDERR)                                                   ^

W20140608-02:12:51.176(3)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined

W20140608-02:12:51.181(3)? (STDERR)     at a.lang.months (packages/momentjs/moment\min\langs.min.js:1)

W20140608-02:12:51.182(3)? (STDERR)     at moment (packages/momentjs/moment\min\langs.min.js:1)

W20140608-02:12:51.183(3)? (STDERR)     at packages/momentjs.js:45:4

W20140608-02:12:51.184(3)? (STDERR)     at packages/momentjs.js:73:3

W20140608-02:12:51.184(3)? (STDERR)     at C:\work\telescope\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:185

W20140608-02:12:51.185(3)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)

W20140608-02:12:51.186(3)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach(C:\Users\nm2arch\AppData\Local\.meteor\tool81bb6\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)

W20140608-02:12:51.187(3)? (STDERR)     at C:\work\telescope\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:102

=> Exited with code: 8

=> Started proxy.

=> Started MongoDB.

W20140608-02:12:51.171(3)? (STDERR)

W20140608-02:12:51.172(3)? (STDERR)
C:\Users\nm2arch\AppData\Local\.meteor\tools\edf8981bb6\lib\node_modules\fibere.js:173

W20140608-02:12:51.173(3)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);

W20140608-02:12:51.175(3)? (STDERR)                                                   ^

W20140608-02:12:51.176(3)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined

W20140608-02:12:51.181(3)? (STDERR)     at a.lang.months (packages/momentjs/moment\min\langs.min.js:1)

W20140608-02:12:51.182(3)? (STDERR)     at moment (packages/momentjs/moment\min\langs.min.js:1)

W20140608-02:12:51.183(3)? (STDERR)     at packages/momentjs.js:45:4

W20140608-02:12:51.184(3)? (STDERR)     at packages/momentjs.js:73:3

W20140608-02:12:51.184(3)? (STDERR)     at C:\work\telescope\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:185

W20140608-02:12:51.185(3)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)

W20140608-02:12:51.186(3)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach(C:\Users\nm2arch\AppData\Local\.meteor\tool81bb6\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)

W20140608-02:12:51.187(3)? (STDERR)     at C:\work\telescope\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:102

=> Exited with code: 8
```

(... and the above pattern is repeated several times...)

Of course, nothing happens at "localhost:3000", since the app does not run properly.

I cannot figure out what else needs to be done in order for someone to run the Telescope project (as of June 2014) with Meteor in a Windows environment.

I believe that other users will have similar problems (not exactly the same necessarily) with Meteor projects and Windows, so it would be good to find solutions here (at least for these particular problems).

Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend using Vagrant to run meteor on Windows.  See https://gist.github.com/gabrielhpugliese/5855677

Comment: Thank you alanfie, if I use the Vagrant option will I be able to develop my Meteor application in WebStorm for Windows without more hassles? I have the feeling that I will have to be careful of many things (version control, etc.?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be quite specifically that the 'window' variable is not found in the 'moment' package.

This package is used for displaying and manipulating times, and is usually used on the browser side where 'window' is usually/always present. Your logs show that this is being used on the server side.

My guess is that you haven't cloned the packages quite right, and therefore you have a version of moment that hasn't been adapted for meteor.

I suspect if you took the same files and ran them on Linux or a Mac you'd get exactly the same error.

If you give details of exactly which repositories you cloned, I may be able to spot the problem.

***UPDATE***: For reference, here is what I did to get Telescope working.

First of all I downloaded Telescope to a subdirectory:

  `git clone https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope.git
  cd Telescope`

Next, I used a simple-ish Powershell script to automate what the essence of what Meteorite does.
If there are only a couple of dependencies you can do this by hand, but Telescope has a few:

```
powershell
$root = Get-Location
$json = Get-Content smart.lock | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$names = $json.dependencies.packages | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty | Select -expand Name
foreach ($name in $names)
{
    echo ('-' * 78)
    echo "Installing package: $name"
    $p = $json.dependencies.packages.$name
    cd "$root\packages"
    [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
    echo "=> git clone --recursive $($p.git) $name"
    git clone --recursive $($p.git) $name

    cd "$root\packages\$name"
    [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
    echo "=> git checkout $($p.commit)"
    git checkout $($p.commit)
}
```

Then we need to add the packages to Meteor (still in PowerShell syntax):

```
cd $root
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
echo "=> meteor add $names"
meteor add $names
```

Finally I ran up meteor:

```
meteor
[[[[[ C:\meteor\Telescope ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

Hopefully the script will help others.

***UPDATE 2***: This version of he script will work with PowerShell v2:

```
$root = Get-Location
$lock = "$(gc smart.lock)" -replace '[\s{},]+',' '
$lock = $lock -replace '^.*"packages":\s*',''
$lock = $lock -replace '"([^"]*)": "git": "([^"]*)" "tag": "[^"]*" "commit": "(\w+)" ',"`$1,`$2,`$3`n"

$names = @()
$lock -Split "`n" | Select-String ',' | %{
    $fields = $_ -Split ','
    $name = $fields[0]
    $git = $fields[1]
    $commit = $fields[2]

    $names += $name

    echo ('-' * 78)
    echo "Installing package: $name"
    cd "$root\packages"
    [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
    echo "=> git clone --recursive $git $name"
    git clone --recursive $git $name

    cd "$root\packages\$name"
    [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
    echo "=> git checkout $commit"
    git checkout $commit
}
cd $root
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
echo "=> meteor add $names"
meteor add $names
```

Comment: Indeed, I had problems specifically with cloning the "moment" package, as it appears (from smart.lock) that Telescope wants both the "moment" and the "momentjs" packages (why? are they different?).

I did clone both, but this process is not seamless.

1. "momentjs" git repository says:  " This package is being removed in favor of https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment"
Which is the OTHER ("moment") package, so what do we do with that?

2. The "moment" git is mostly **empty** and has a "subgit" (submodule?), so I cloned that too **inside** the "moment/lib" directory.

Wasn't that OK?

Comment: Also, you mention about the "package" running on server-side. I just added the packages to the "/packages" folder, I did not intervene with the logic of the application.

I see that Telescope uses moment-related code in some files in the generic "/lib" folder, so I assume this is where the moment tries to run on the server?

But this is how Telescope is written by default, I made no changes, shouldn't this work without hassles? (assuming I did the cloning correctly?). Thanks!

Comment: @user2078023 My comments about the error in moment and it usually being used on the client side were more to help explain the error message. I know moment can be used on the server side (but 'window') is a client thing.

Comment: As for the submodule, I would expect that the submodule would automatically loaded when you did the checkout.  On this topic, did you checkout the exact revision/tag mentioned in the smart.lock file?

Comment: Thanks!

the smart.lock file says "2.6.0" for "meteor" and I use this one.

It also says ""v2.1.0.2" for "meteorjs" and I also use this one.

Still, I am confused, are BOTH the "moment" AND "momentjs" packages needed? (maybe this creates conflict?)

The "momentjs" says in README: 

"This package is being removed in favor of https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment"

However, there are references to "momentjs" inside the project (as well as to "moment").

I am struggling to find what I did wrong (wish: please someone create MRT for Windows, the VC-backed METEOR team should just pay him).

Comment: I tried your script and it fails here:
"The term 'ConvertFrom-Json' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Comment: Sadly, `ConvertFrom-Json` was added in PowerShell v3 so I suspect you are still on PowerShell 2. You can just type `$PSVersionTable` to check. FWIW Instructions for updating are in: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh847837.aspx  but I'll see if I can work around it. By the way there is an activity to port Meteorite and it is close, but the official new packaging system is imminent too.

Comment: I did checkout everything (this is what I forgot to do) and the "moment" problems are gone, HOWEVER I still cannot start the app because it says:
"Error reading fast-render inject_data.html:  Unknown asset: lib/server/inject_data.html"
Any ideas what is wrong with that?
Thank you SO MUCH for any help.

Comment: I've added a PowerShell v2 version. As for the fast-renderer issue, I'm not sure but I suspect something isn't at the right version. Maybe try a clean version of Telescope with the script?

Comment: GREAT StephenD, that WORKED! Thank you, GREAT WORK. Could it be that my mistake was that I did not use the "meteor add" command? Because I saw that they were already there inside the ".meteor/packages" file (from the repository itself). So, does "meteor add" perform MORE actions than just adding the names of the packages inside that file?

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes, `meteor add` does do a bit more than just editing the file.